# При получение параметра функции класса его сбрасывают

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Любая функция класса при получении разности `a-b` сбрасывает ее и вставляет `-8526541`. Почему?

В коде есть лишние детали, не обращайте внимания.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Time
{
    int hour;
    int minute;

    void allFromMinutes()
    {
        hour = minute / 60;
        minute %= 60;
    }
public:

    Time() : hour(0), minute(0)
    {}
    Time(int hour, int minute) : hour(hour), minute(minute)
    {}
    Time(Time const& adolf) : Time(adolf.getHour(), adolf.getMinute())
    {}

    void addMinutes(int minutes)
    {
        minute += minutes;
        while (minute >= 60)
        {
            minute -= 60;
            hour++;
        }
    }
    void addHour(int hour)
    {
        this->hour += hour;
        while (this->hour > 24)
        {
            this->hour -= 24;
        }
    }
    void removeMinutes(int minutes)
    {
        while (minutes > 0)
        {
            minute -= minutes;
            if (minute < 0)
            {
                hour--;
                minutes = (-minute) - 1;
                minute = 59;
            }
            else
            {
                minutes -= minutes;
            }
        }
    }
    void removeHour(int hour)
    {
        this->hour -= hour;
        if (this->hour < 0)
        {
            this->hour += 24;
        }
    }
    void setHour(int hour) { this->hour = hour; }
    void setMinute(int minute) { this->minute = minute; }

    int allToMinutes() const
    {
        return minute + hour * 60;
    }

    int getHour() const { return hour; }
    int getMinute() const {
        return minute;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Time const& a);
    Time& operator=(Time const& a)
    {
        setHour(a.getHour());
        setMinute(a.getMinute());
        return *this;
    }
    friend bool operator==(Time const& a, Time const& b)
    {
        return (a.getHour() == b.getHour() && a.getMinute() == b.getMinute());
    }
    Time& operator-(Time const& a) const
    {
        Time temp(*this);
        Time res(0, 0);
        while (temp.getHour() != a.getHour())
        {
            temp.addHour(1);
            res.addHour(1);
        }

        if (temp.getMinute() > a.getMinute())
        {
            res.removeHour(1);
            res.setMinute(60 - (temp.getMinute() - a.getMinute()));
        }
        else if (temp.getMinute() < a.getMinute())
        {
            res.setMinute((a.getMinute() - temp.getMinute()));
        }

        return res;
    }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Time const& a)
{
    if (a.getHour() < 10) { out << 0; }
    out << a.getHour() << ':';
    if (a.getMinute() < 10) { out << 0; }
    out << a.getMinute();

    return out;
}

int main() {

    Time a(23, 30);
    Time b(1, 30);

    Time c(a);
    c = a - b;
    cout << c << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не вникая в код: `main.cpp:96:14: warning: reference to local variable 'res' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гм!

```
Time& operator-(Time const& a) const
{
    Time temp(*this);
    Time res(0, 0);

    ....

    return res;
}
```

По-моему, возврат ссылки на локальную переменную, нет?

Посмотрите на [этот вариант](https://ideone.com/2P9MzD).